# Using substringFromIndex: with NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I am working on an `NSData` object that is 4840 bytes, and want to omit the first 20 bytes and fetch the rest. Are the substring methods `substringFromIndex:` / `substringToIndex:` applicable to `NSData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close, `NSData` has a method [`subdataWithRange:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/subdataWithRange:). You can make a range with the function [`NSMakeRange`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakeRange) and then use that range to produce an `NSData` trimmed as you like.

An example:

```
// Create NSData
NSString* myString = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur cras amet.";
NSData*   myData   = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (myData != nil && myData.length > 20) {

  // Create trimmed NSData
  NSData* newData = [myData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(20, myData.length - 20)];
  if (newData != nil) {

    // Test
    NSString* newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: newData 
                                                encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", newString);
    // -> "t amet, consectetur cras amet."
  }
}
```

Comment: looking for a complete example, but this is helpful

Comment: NSData *d1 = [myData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];

Comment: @circuitry I added a complete example to illustrate how `subdataWithRange:` might be used

Answer (score 4):

Reading the documentation for `NSData`, there is a method there which will let you specify a range of bytes: [`-getBytes:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIACCFDG). Use [`NSMakeRange()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BAJDGHDI) to set the range.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (NSData *)subdataWithRange:(NSRange)range;
```

Comment: That is not a delegate method.